# Excluir e recriar variáveis em um mesmo escopo de funções diferentes

Tags: php

estou criando logs para qualquer momento que o meu sistema tiver um comportamento inesperado, onde não necessariamente irá travar o meu sistema, por exemplo um acesso indevido usando um token desconhecido ou uma tentativa de brute force, a minha intenção é utilizar uma função similar:

```
function create_log( $filename, $log ) {
    file_put_contents( 
        $filename.'.log', '[START]'.
        json_encode($_REQUEST).PHP_EOL.
        json_encode($_SESSION).PHP_EOL.
        "Log ".$log.PHP_EOL.'[END]'.PHP_EOL
    , FILE_APPEND );
}
```

Ou seja, salvo informações que vieram no corpo da requisição, seja lá qual for o método, e informações da sessão atual, acontece que existem alguns dados que não gostaria de salvar nesse log, tipo informações de dados de cartão de crédito dos clientes, senha de login no sistema e etc... então estou pensando em uma função que remova essas informações antes de chamar a função `create_log` e uma que recrie essas informações para não travar o fluxo do meu código caso essas informações ainda sejam necessárias.

Em uma versão mais antiga eu utilizava algo parecido:

```
function create_log( $filename, $log ) {
    unset_fields();
    file_put_contents(...);
    reset_fields();
}

function unset_fields(){
    $_SESSION["senha"] = $_REQUEST["senha"];
    unset($_REQUEST["senha"]);
}

function reset_fields(){
    $_REQUEST["senha"] = $_SESSION["senha"];
}
```

Ou seja eu usava variáveis de sessão como variáveis auxiliares, porém agora tenho a necessidade também de logar informações da sessão do cliente que está acessando o sistema, e com o intuito de melhorar o código, estou tentando algo do tipo:

```
$_REQUEST["remover"] = 5;
$_REQUEST["não remover"] = 5;
// variável request antes de remover os campos sensíveis
var_dump($_REQUEST); 
$arr = array("não existe", "remover");
unset_fields($arr);
// aqui viria o file_put_contents
var_dump($_REQUEST);
reset_fields($arr);
// aqui eu necessitava da global $_REQUEST no seu estado inicial
var_dump($_REQUEST);

function unset_fields(array $array){
    foreach($array as $val) {
        if(isset($_REQUEST[$val])){
            ${$val} = $_REQUEST[$val];
            unset($_REQUEST[$val]);
        }
    }
}
function reset_fields(array $array){
    foreach($array as $val) {
        if(isset(${$val})){
            $_REQUEST[$val] = ${$val} ;
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima imprime:

```
array(2) {
  ["remover"]=>
  int(5)
  ["não remover"]=>
  int(5)
}
array(1) {
  ["não remover"]=>
  int(5)
}
array(1) {
  ["não remover"]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Ou seja, o meu problema está no escopo da variável criada como auxiliar, ela só existe dentro da função `unset_fields` e ainda assim se eu tornar ela "global" ou se definir como constante, corro o risco da variável conflitar com alguma outra que já exista.

Comment: Só não entendi direito porquê você salva as informações sensíveis em sessão sendo que você as gravará em arquivo da mesma forma. Você apenas passou de `$_REQUEST` para `$_SESSION`, mas ambos são gravados no log, não? Aliás, não ficaria mais fácil você copiar o conteúdo destas superglobais para variáveis locais e filtrar essas? Assim você não iria precisar se preocupar em recuperar o contexto inicial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado na pergunta - e se entendi corretamente o problema - você não precisa alterar as variáveis super globais para gerar um arquivo de *log*. Sinceramente, isso nem parece fazer muito sentido, justamente pelo fato que pode prejudicar outras partes da aplicação, tal como você quer evitar. O mais prático a se fazer seria copiar seus valores para variáveis locais e manipular apenas essas locais. Algo como:

```
function create_log($filename, $log)
{
    // Copia as superglobais para variáveis locais:
    $request = $_REQUEST;
    $session = $_SESSION;

    // Define quais são as informações sensíveis:
    $filter = ["password", "credit_card"];

    // Filtra as informações sensíveis:
    $request = array_filter($request, function ($key) use ($filter) {
        return !in_array($key, $filter);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    $session = array_filter($session, function ($key) use ($filter) {
        return !in_array($key, $filter);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    // Gera a mensagem de log:
    file_put_contents( 
        $filename.'.log', '[START]'.
        json_encode($request).PHP_EOL.
        json_encode($session).PHP_EOL.
        "Log ".$log.PHP_EOL.'[END]'.PHP_EOL
    , FILE_APPEND );
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/dNIpE6).

Considerando uma entrada como:

```
$_REQUEST = [
    "username" => "admin",
    "password" => "pass",
    "credit_card" => "000000"
];

$_SESSION = [
    "id" => 1
];
```

Ao gerar o log, os valores de `password` e `credit_card` serão filtrados por estarem na lista de informações sensíveis.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer essas funções dentro de uma classe e criar a variável da própria classe `$this->XXX` ou você pode também transformar em uma constante definida desta forma `define("NOME_DA_CONSTANTE", "VALOR_DESTA_CONSTANTE");`